# How do I login to Nexenta in Expert Mode?

Tags: zfs, nexenta

When I login to the a Nexenta machine via SSH I have to type the following commands:

```
nmc@nexenta:/$ option expert_mode=1

nmc@nexenta:/$ !bash
You are about to enter the Unix ("raw") shell and execute low-level Unix command(s). Warning: using low-level Unix commands is not recommended! Execute?  Yes
```

Can I login and just be in expert mode already?  Doing this each time is annoying.

<sub>Note: I don't want to write a script to execute this each time, that's not really the solution I'm looking for.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the expert_mode option persistent here. Run `option expert_mode = 1 -s`. The `-s` makes the setting permanent. From now on, you'd just need to run `!bash` to obtain a shell from the `nmc` console.

You can also ssh as the `admin` user and use `su` when needed.

However, NexentaStor is really meant to be an appliance managed either by the web interface or the `nmc` command line console. Your trips to the raw Unix shell should be limited, but if you do need to go there, you shouldn't have an issue typing the two commands to obtain access. I think of it like `sudo`. The current NexentaStor warning looks like this:

```
nmc@nexenta:/$ !bash

You are about to enter the Unix ("raw") shell and execute low-level Unix command(s). CAUTION: NexentaStor
appliance is not a general purpose operating system: managing the appliance via Unix shell is NOT
recommended. This management console (NMC) is the command-line interface (CLI) of the appliance,
specifically designed for all command-line interactions. Using Unix shell without authorization of your
support provider may not be supported and MAY VOID your license agreement. To display the agreement,
please use 'show appliance license agreement'.

Proceed anyway? (type No to return to the management console)  Yes
```

Be sure to execute `setup appliance nms restart` after you're done working in the bash shell to refresh the web console's values.